# Tab is not working in my local machine using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying create tab using angular js.I am trying in chrome.Referered these code http://jsfiddle.net/Wijmo/ywUYQ/ and included these file in code

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
  angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js">  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/
 2.3.1/css/bootstrap-  combined.min.css">
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/
 twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Got the result like these way

```
 BootStrap Tab Component
 This is the content of the first tab.
 This is the content of the second tab.
```

I have no idea,why these is not working in my site?is nt any problem of chrome version?Anybody help me?My chrome version is Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: your fiddle works fine in my chrome..any error? Did you check that all required resources (angular, bootstrap, bootstrap directives) loaded fine in your machine using browser developer tool.

Comment: updated above,included 3 files in my file,give that included file name above

Answer (score 0):

You need to include bootstrap dependencies with it. I suggest you to know about Bootstrap before going forward.

You just cant create like that in fly. Tabs are part of bootstrap what you were looking for. Add this two line pieces of code below angularjs declaration.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Get to know a little basics before you post something. And accept this answer when it works

Comment: Can create tab with out bootstrap? with only angular js